# What is the maximum fuel amount that fits into the rare Boeing 737-700ER version?

Tags: boeing-737

Title is self explanatory: what is the exact maximum fuel amount that fits into the still rare-to-see Boeing 737-700ER version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Payload/range diagrams from the [Boeing Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning manual](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/737.pdf) (page 95), the fuel capacity is 32 539 kg (71 737 lb)

[image: Payload range diagrams fro the 737-700ER/-700ERW/-700C/-700CW/ BBJ1]

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for such delay in commenting it!